# Regex extract text between single quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have the following SQL insert statement

```
INSERT INTO table 1 VALUES ('abc', 'foo\'bar', '123');
```

and I am trying to extract the values into array as

```
array('abc', 'foo\'bar', '123');
```

(Note: a given string can contain nested single quote but it is always escaped)

This is the regex that I am currenly using

```
'(.*?)(?<!\\\\)'
```

It works pretty well, but it makes a lot of backtracking steps for large strings and hits php.ini limitation **pcre.backtrack_limit**

How can I reduce the number of backtracking steps? I've read about possessions, atomic groups and backtracking control verbs but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Clearly use a SQL parser. About finding a non escaped quote, the answer is in the pattern design, not in a special feature: [`'([^'\\\\]*+(?s:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*+)'`](https://regex101.com/r/0yNzpD/1)

Comment: Parsing SQL text seems like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. I'm tempted to recommend using SQLite to actually insert the values into an in-memory database, then read them back.